# If $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable does $\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}(\int_a^b|f(x)|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)|$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, supremum-and-infimum, riemann-integration

Several posts on this site ask for a proof of the statement

> If $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, $\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}(\int_a^b|f(x)|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)|$.

Need $f$ only be Riemann integrable for $\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}(\int_a^b|f(x)|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)|$ to be true?

If so, where can I find a proof of this that does not involve measure theory?

Comment: did you meant to write the $p$ norm of $f$ ? Otherwise, what you wrote is pointwise and is not at all related to the supremum.

Comment: Yes. That was a mistake. I have corrected the question.

Comment: Well $\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}(|f(x)|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)|$ is certainly wrong.  The LHS depends on $x$ and the RHS doesn't.  I think you want something like: If $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, $\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}(\int_a^b |f(x)|^p\,dx)^{\frac{1}{p}}=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)|$.  Try to prove it yourself: $\varepsilon, \delta$ style.

Comment: Yes. This is true even for Lebesgue measurable function (in which case, the supremum norm is slightly modified to essential sup). This is called continuity of norm. I proved it long time ago. You may search my posts and hopefully you can find it.

Comment: @Danny Pak-Keung Chan Thank you!

Comment: @GEdgar You are correct as to the fact that there was a mistake in the original version of the post. Also, I have proven the case where $f$ is continuous.

Comment: The statement is not true for Riemann integrable functions. Consider $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and $f(x)=0$ for $0\le x<1$ and $f(1)=1.$ You need essential supremum which coincides with supremum for continuous functions.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc That answered my question. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $M=\max \; |f(x)|$, is $M=\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} \left(\int_a^b|f(x)|^n\,\mathrm dx\right)^{1/n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88300/if-fx-is-continuous-on-a-b-and-m-max-fx-is-m-lim-limits-n)

Comment: @Danny Pak-Keung Chan See my comment.

Comment: @Danny Pak-Keung Chan What is a.e.?

Comment: a.e. means "almost everywhere"

Comment: Another, more handy definition is $A={\rm essup}f(x)=\sup\{ a\,:\, \mu\{x\,:\, f(x)>a\}>0\}$. Basing on this definition the proof for Lebesgue integrable function $f$ is easy.

Comment: You may read

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2845992/lim-p-to-r-f-p-f-r/2860957#2860957

and

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3878358/how-to-show-that-f-lp-to-f-l-infty-as-p-to-infty-if-f-in/3878434#3878434

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was answered in comment with a counterexample.

Comment: @Anne Bauval By replacing the supremum norm with essential supremum norm, the statement is true (even for Lebesgue measurable function). May be it is a good idea to modify the title of the question.

Comment: A remark about essential sup norm. We say that a real number $M$
is an essential upper bound of $f$ if $f(x)\leq M$ for $x$-a.e..
The essential sup norm of $f$ , denoted by $||f||_{\infty}$ , is
defined by $||f||_{\infty}=\inf\{M\mid M\mbox{ is an essential upper bound of }|f|\}.$

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Yes we know but that was not the point, and the OP said Ryszard's answer was what he was looking for. When he understood his statement was false, he stopped asking for an elementary proof for non continuous Riemann integrable functions. So I think changing his title would betray his intent.